# Should lists of users in an organization include yourself?

Tags: tables, users, ux-field, administration

We have a platform that allows access to multiple people. There are two types of roles - Admin and Member.

On the page where it displays the list of people, is it standard practice to include yourself in the list? So, If I'm logged-in as "John Doe", should I then expect to see myself in the list?

If the user were an Admin, that means that they are able to delete other users. If "John Doe" were Admin, they, however, will not be able to delete themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone with **explicit access** should be shown in an access list, including yourself. If you're an admin because you started the group, you should be on the list; it's a consistency principle.

As an example - if you didn't see your own name, you wouldn't show up in the group member count, which might be important (let's say your group caps membership at 50 people until a paid upgrade; if you're not on the list, the count would show as 49, even though there are 50 people in the group. Or it would show as 50 members, with only 49 names.)

It's also a little extra assurance that you're a member. Maybe you don't access the group for seven years, forget about it. If you stumble into it again one day, not seeing yourself as a member might be disorienting.

People with **implicit access** don't need to be shown in the member list. Example: your IT infosec team, which can monitor all communications, but isn't actively participating in the community. Showing them might confuse other members ("Who is this John Doe, and why is he here?")

It's okay to not be able to delete your own name in a member list. You just wouldn't see the same controls next to your own name as you would with others; that's a commonly understood administration pattern. Hopefully you would have other controls such as "remove Admin role" or "leave group" that still function like deletion but are more contextual to your role.

Comment: I totally agree with @Izquierdo. Think about HR application. wouldn't you expect to see yourself as a team member, as a manager (per your role)? in the Org chart? If you are part of the users - you should see yourself.